# With magisk, how to bypass boot-time password input?

Tags: boot, encryption, magisk

I have an phone with magisk and termux installed, and now functions as a mini server at home. Whenever I need to reboot the phone, I need to manually unlock the phone with GUI to get termux running, so I can not reboot when away from home.

Is there a way to let magisk decrypt the phone programmatically, with password written in some config/script file?

Comment: If you keep the phone at home then why not just remove the password?

Comment: @Firelord IIRC, FBE is always there with or without password, so even I removed the  password, android need manual swipe up at boot to get other non-core app running. See reference here: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/266720/android-file-encryption-without-screen-lock

Comment: You can disable encryption from `fstab`. You then have to format the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a shell script that runs at start-up. It's just a matter of timing.

`/data/adb/service.d/99unlock`

```
#!/system/bin/sh
sleep 30
input keyevent KEYCODE_WAKEUP
sleep 5
input keyevent KEYCODE_SPACE
input text <SIM PIN>
input keyevent KEYCODE_SPACE
sleep 5
input keyevent KEYCODE_SPACE
input text <PASSWORD>
```

Make sure the script is executable:

```
chmod 0700 /data/adb/service.d/99unlock
```